# Simple queries to Redshift really slow

Tags: performance, amazon-rds, aws, redshift, query-performance

I just started testing AWS Redshift and populated a single node with the [AWS sample data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-create-sample-db.html).

Querying a table with 10 or ~400 rows takes around 2 seconds, uncached.

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, but I assumed that would be a lot faster. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks! Any feedback appreciated.

[image]

Comment: But did you figure out how to get acceptable performance on small tables with Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea around Redshift is *not to run in a single node*. It is actually designed to run in a sharded cluster and it is expected to have very bad numbers within only one node. If you look at the [internals](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_internal_arch_system_operation.html) you'll see that is actually designed to run on top of a set of nodes, adding an extra layer for the query processing.

If you are already familiar with the basics, you can check the [Best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-tables-best-practices.html).

Comment: sorry, this still doesn't explain the case, it is still a very small table with too few computations to be done. just by doubling the number of instances shouldn't make the performance better on very simple tasks

Comment: I also experienced that Redshift takes more time for every fresh queries